# Netty's local transport for communication within a JVM

Tags: java, netty

I am reading chapter *4.3.4. Local transport for communication within a JVM* of the *Netty in Action* book. There I find:

> Netty provides a local transport for asynchronous communication
> between clients and servers running in the same JVM.

However, no example is given. Does anyone have more knowledge about this topic and can give an example?

What I am interested in is implementing a reverse proxy using Netty.

In this case we would have a web server receiving requests and using that *local transport* to forward them to a client, that finally sends them to other host. Then receiving back response from the client and using again the *local transport* to return the response to the web server which sends it to the user. So the JVM that runs Netty would be just a reverse proxy between the web clients and local machines.

Comment: Search for examples using DefaultEventLoopGroup. This class is used for local communication. Here are some examples http://useof.org/java-open-source/io.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoopGroup/3. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Orcun. I found in the Netty in Action book that is possible to use direct approach to write from one channel to other channel's Context object, what solves my prolem.